# From which LEGO set are these brown and green parts?

Tags: set-identification

These LEGO parts are mostly brown tones with some green.
They look like they go together but I don't know how
and don't know the set they would belong to.
I hope you can help.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

These appear to be largely from set [21160 - The Illager Raid](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=21160-1) :

[image]

But there are several parts in there that did not come from that set, eg. :

- [Minifigure Armor Breastplate Rectangular (Minecraft) in Pearl Gold](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=19723&idColor=156) which only comes in 4 sets

[image]

- [Wave Rounded Straight with Bar End (Castle Dragon Flame / Seaweed / Water) in Trans-Orange](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6126b#T=C&C=98) (or possibly [6126](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6126#T=C&C=98) - hard to tell from the picture) which does not come in any minecraft sets

[image]

- [Brick 1 x 1 in Trans-Light Blue](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3005#T=C&C=15) which does not come in any minecraft sets

[image]

So it appears some foreign parts snuck in, and neither is the set complete.